# Checking schema on ingest Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a file that changes schema quite often.

For example, in the below, the invoice date can be of differing formats and invoice value can be of differing format (sometimes with a $ sometimes without and sometimes with other currency).

I want to be able to scan the dataframe column by column and say:
- If there is a non numeric character (except a . ) in the invoice value column, then.... I can then define the schema to apply to the file differently.

Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean final column content for different type of file should be unique or different? For example, if one file contains invoice value - $5.0 and other file contains 6.5, at the end should be stored as 5 and 6.5 in invoice_value column.

Comment: I mean - if there is a $ in the invoiceValue column, then I want to set the structtype of that field to StringType(). If it doesn't, I want to set it to be float

Comment: `inferschema` option while reading the file should help you, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code, here invoice value will be floating number and date format have taken for example, you can change it as per required.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = sc.parallelize([["ThoughtStorm","11/23/2019","$6.09","true"],
["Talane","3/28/2019","£7.20","true"]]).toDF(("company_name","invoice_date","invoice_value","paid"))
df = df.withColumn("invoice_value",regexp_extract(col("invoice_value"), """([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+""", 0))
df = df.withColumn("invoice_date", f.date_format(f.to_date(f.unix_timestamp(col("invoice_date"), "mm/dd/yyyy").cast("timestamp")), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
df.show()
+------------+------------+-------------+----+
|company_name|invoice_date|invoice_value|paid|
+------------+------------+-------------+----+
|ThoughtStorm|  2019-01-23|         6.09|true|
|      Talane|  2019-01-28|         7.20|true|
+------------+------------+-------------+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

for `InvoiceValue` you can use `regexp_extract`.  The regex is not perfect, but you got the idea.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val data = List(
  ("$50.60"),
  ("$5.60"),
  ("£500.400"),
  ("100"),
  ("100.20")
).toDF("InvoiceValue")

data.show

val newdata = data.withColumn("value", regexp_extract($"InvoiceValue","""\D*(\d{1,4}\.{1}\d{1,4}).*""", 1))
newdata.show
```

**output**

```
data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [InvoiceValue: string]
+------------+
|InvoiceValue|
+------------+
|      $50.60|
|       $5.60|
|    £500.400|
|         100|
|      100.20|
+------------+

newdata: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [InvoiceValue: string, value: string]
+------------+-------+
|InvoiceValue|  value|
+------------+-------+
|      $50.60|  50.60|
|       $5.60|   5.60|
|    £500.400|500.400|
|         100|    100|
|      100.20| 100.20|
+------------+-------+
```